# Requests to GAE app fail with Connection Reset

Tags: google-app-engine

Our GAE python app exposes an API that is hit by an external client system (Java-based, if that matters). The large majority of requests (tens of thousands per day) work fine, however some few requests (less than 10 per day) fail with the client side reporting 'Connection Reset by Peer' error. When that happens, the client system has fired multiple API calls that finish successfully, so we rule out the case of connectivity issues on the client side.

The GAE logs show only app-related failures but other kinds of failures (e.g. connection errors) don't appear in the logs, so we can't really tell why these API calls are failing.

Is there any way to better identify such issues other that the logs?

The GAE module that accepts the API calls has the following scaling properties

```
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
  idle_timeout: 1m
```

and at the time of failure, only 2 (out of maximum 5) instances where running, so the GAE module is below its scaling limits. The API calls are served on-average in less that 500ms and we have never seen a log error for exceeding the 60" limit of requests. Overall, the module doesn't seem overloaded. Could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the best solution to fix your issue is to try and have an [exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) algorithm in your code when the connection gets reset, as it would "fail gracefully" and retry it.

I would also suggest moving to [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#automatic_scaling_1), where playing with your max pending latency and min pending latency you might help with these kind of issues. I don't have specifics on what would fix your issue, but I guess that fiddling with these could provide some results.